# discord.py raise different errors for different check failures

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord.py bot with the command `test`. I want to run two checks, first check if the person running it is the bot owner and check if the command is run in a dm. If the bot is run in a dm I want it to send a message but if its not the owner I want it to run a different message. how would I do this?

```
@bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.check(is_owner)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Good job you passed the checks!")
@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if failed guild_only():
        await ctx.send("Hey only use this in a guild")
    if failed is_owner():
        await ctx.send("You're not the owner!!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isinstance()`.

`isinstance` checks whether if an object has the specified type. For example, `isinstance(3, int)` checks if 3 is an integer (which it is and therefore returns `True`). In your case you could check if the error is `commands.NoPrivateMessage`, which is raised by `guild_only`, or if the error is `commands.NotOwner`, which is raised by `is_owner`. The correct code would be:

```py
@test.error
async def test_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateChannel):
        await ctx.send("Hey only use this in a guild")
    if isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
        await ctx.send("You're not the owner!!")
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!